# how to implement jump call to appropriate vtable entry

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, vtable

I am working on an assignment on compiler design. In the code generation part I am stuck with how to create instructions which will ensure that appropriate method is called at run time. The language is a very small subset of C++.

let's say:

```
void main()
{
  Animal* a;
  a = new Cow;
  //what code should be generated to ensure that object 'a' calls Cow::Init here
  a->Init(5);
}

class Cow : public Animal{
 void Init(int h)
 {
   height = h;
 }
}

class Animal {
 int height; 
 virtual void Init(int h){
   height = h;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `Animal *a;` Why don't you see for yourself by generatng the assembly code? Besides that `vtable` `vptr` mechanisms are highly implementation specific.

Comment: @Als any general idea would be helpful. The thing is I'm not good at reading assembly code. For the homework there are a set of functions which generate assembly code.

Comment: This new code, edited one, is the way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a very simple way of doing this(note: this excludes optimizing for know calls at compile time):
if your class has any virtual members (including inherited), then its very first member becomes a pointer to a vftable. the vftable is constant *per class definition* which is why you need only a pointer.

from there, each unique function is assigned an index in that vftable, so each unique name (note: by name I mean the symbol name including types, but no class-namespace qualification) has a unique index, then the table is filled in from the class at the very top of the inheritance tree down to your current working class definition.

In doing so, newer redifinitions of virtual function will overwrite the older entries that share their index. calling the functions then becomes trivial as you just generate a call to the index for that function's name-index.

So in your example, `Animal` has a vftable with 1 entry, `Init(int)`, which is assigned the unique index of 0. so you have a vftable looking like so:

```
;Animal - vftable
&Animal::Init //note: this isn't a class member pointer in the C++ sense, its a namespaced function pointer if you will
```

then when you build the vftable for `Cow`, you use `Animals` as a base and add in the virtual functions, in this case `Init(int)`, but it already has a unique index of 0, so we overwrite the function at index 0:

```
;Cow - vftable
&Cow::Init
```

then if we have the call:

```
a->Init(5);
```

we simply transform that to:

```
a->vftable[0](5);
```

where 0 was the unique index allocated to `Init(int)`.

an assembly example just in case that helps:

```
;ecx contains our class pointer
mov eax,[ecx] ;get the vftable ptr
mov eax,[eax] ; get the ptr at (vftable + (unique_index * sizeof(func_ptr)))
push 5 ;push our arg 5, ecx is already setup for __thiscall
call eax ; let it rip!
```

note: this all assumes your symbol table is setup to be able to detect virtual functions passed through inheritance or those that become virtual from inheritance.

---

If this where to be optimized you could analyze `a` and find that its only assigned a value once, thus you can morph its class to the class of the value it was assigned, `Cow`. then seeing as you have a class at the *end* of a derivation chain, you can fold away the vftable call and use a call directly to `Cow::Init`, how this is a lot more tricky, and there are many ways of optimizing out vftable calls, for a project it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

This can be expressed in lightweight C++, if you find it more readable than assembly (I do). I will restrict myself to C (mostly) and just adds inheritance to avoid lots of casting.

For clarity, the implementation details will be prefixed by `__`. Note that those identifiers are reserved to the implementation, in general, so you should normally not use them in your programs.

---

**A typesafe virtual dispatching method**.

*Note: limited to simple inheritance (single base, no virtual inheritance)*

Let's create the `Animal` class.

```
struct __AnimalTableT;

struct Animal { __AnimalTableT const * const __vptr; int height; }

void AnimalInit(Animal* a, int height) {
  a->height = height;
}
```

We reserve the space for a pointer to the virtual table in Animal, and express the method as an external function to make the `this` explicit.

Next, we "create" the virtual table. Note that an array in C need be composed of similar elements, so here we will use a slightly higher level approach.

```
struct __AnimalTableT {
  typedef void (*InitFunction)(int);

  InitFunction Init;
};
static __AnimalTableT const __AnimalTable = { &AnimalInit };
```

Now, let us create a cow:

```
struct Cow: Animal {};

void CowInit(Animal* a, int height) {
  Cow* c = static_cast<Cow*>(a);
  c->height = height;
}
```

And the associated table:

```
// Note: we could have new functions here (that only Cow has)
// they would be appended after the "Animal" part
struct __CowTableT: __AnimalTableT {};

static __CowTableT const __CowTable = { &CowInit };
```

And the usage:

```
typedef void (*__AnimalInitT)(Animal*,int);

int main() {
  Cow cow = { &__CowTable, 0 };

  __AnimalInitT const __ai = cow.__vptr->Init;
  (*__ai)(&cow, 5);
}
```

---

**And the real one ?**

The real use is slightly more complicated but builds on the same idea.

As you can note it is strange that `CowInit` takes an `Animal*` pointer as its first argument. The issue is that you need a compatible function pointer type with that of the originally overloaded method. In the case of linear inheritance it would not matter much, but in the case of multi-inheritance or virtual inheritance, things get pretty hectic and the `Animal` subpart of `Cow` may not be layed out at the very beginning, resulting in pointer adjustment.

*In real life, we have thunks:*

Well, we can change the signature of `CowInit` to be more natural:

```
void CowInit(Cow* cow, int height);
```

And then, we "bridge" the gap by creating a "thunk" to make the adaptation:

```
void __CowInit(Animal* a, int height) {
  CowInit(static_cast<Cow*>(a), height);
}

static __CowTableT const __CowTable = { &__CowInit };
```

*In real life, we have tables:*

Another remark, is that the use of a struct is very nice, but we are talking about an implementation detail here, so nicety is unnecessary. In general, compilers therefore use a plain array, rather than a struct:

```
typedef (void)(*__GenericFunction)();

static __GenericFunction const __AnimalTable[] = {
  __GenericFunction(&AnimalInit)
};

static __GenericFunction const __CowTable[] = {
  __GenericFunction(&__CowInit)
};
```

This changes the call slightly: you use an index instead of an attribute name and you need to cast back to the appropriate function type.

```
typedef void (*__AnimalInitT)(Animal*,int);

int main() {
  Cow cow = { &__CowTable, 0 };

  // old line: __AnimalInitT const __ai = cow.__vptr->Init;
  __AnimalInit const __ai = __AnimalInit(cow.__vptr[0]);
  (*__ai)(&cow, 5);
}
```

As you can see, the use of tables is really an implementation details.

The really important point here is the introduction of a **thunk** to adapt the function signature. Note that the thunk is introduced at the creation of the table of the *Derived* class (Cow here). In our case, it is unnecessary though, because at low level both objects have the same address, so we could do without, and a smart compiler will not generate it and directly take `&CowInit`.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is often implemented with a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28object-oriented_programming%29), which is a compiler-generated wrapper function.

Comment: Thunks are sometimes used in conjunction with vtables, but are generally not considered a replacement. What do you wrap, and how would that solve the dynamic dispatch?